# How can I pass scope to a callback in node-mysql?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, callback, scope

I get a `client is not defined` error out of the following code:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var conf = {
  'database':'database',
  'user':'user',
  'password':'password'
};

function mysqlQuery(mysql, conf, query, callback) {
  var client = mysql.createClient({
    user:conf.user,
    password:conf.password
  });
  client.query('USE ' + conf.database, function () {
    client.query(query, callback);
  });
}

mysqlQuery(
  mysql,
  conf,
  'SELECT * FROM users;',
  function selectCb(err, results) {
    if (err) {
      throw err;
    }
    console.log(results);
    client.end();
  }
);
```

How can I pass the client variable to my callback function? I have no control on how the callback function will be called as it is called by the mysql module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could [`bind` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) `client` to `callback`. Inside the callback it will be available as `this` then:

```
client.query(query, callback.bind(client))
```

and

```
this.end();
```

You could also pass it as first parameter:

```
client.query(query, callback.bind(null, client))
```

or

```
client.query(query, function(err, results) {
    callback(client, err, results);
});
```

where `callback` is defined as

```
function selectCb(client, err, results) {..};
```

Comment: The third option is even better, it passes `client` as `client` and not `this`, making the code more comprehensible.